# PHPUnit - Version 3.7.21 instead of Version 6 installed

Tags: php, phpunit

I followed the instructions on the [official PHPUnit page](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html#installation.composer) to install PHPUnit 6.

```
composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit ^6.0
```

However, If I go to the project folder and execute `phpunit --version` then I get `PHPUnit 3.7.21 by Sebastian Bergmann.`.

Why is PHPUnit 3.7.21 installed instead of PHPUnit 6?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You run your global PHPUnit version which is installed in another folder. To get the installed version you have to go to the `vendor/bin` folder.

```
vendor/bin/phpunit --version
PHPUnit 6.0.8 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
```

In newer versions you can run it with `bin/phpunit` there should be the executable. When you need another PHP-Version then define it before `php74 bin/phpunit`.

Answer (score 23):

I suppose you have xampp installed? It comes with PHPUnit 3.x.x preinstalled with PEAR which strangely can not be uninstalled with `pear uninstall`. And since its config is in php root folder, that 3-ish version has priority when running phpunit command (even if you have phpunit installed globally) in CMD or PS. How to fix:

1. Go to `xampp/php` folder and delete two files `phpunit` (with no extension) and `phpunit.bat`.  Usually it's enough to prevent older PHPUnit version from being run but let's be on the safer side:
2. Go to `xampp/php/PEAR` dir and delete two folders `PHPUnit` and `PHPUnit2`.
3. Go to Control Panel, then navigate `System and Security->System` and click "Advanced system settings" link on the left. This will open Advanced tab in System Properties window. Click "Environment Variables" button, then under System Variables select "Path" variable and click "Edit..." button. In the new window, click "New" button and type your path to `vendor/bin` folder (if you already installed PHPUnit for your project there will be phpunit.bat file). By default for xamp it looks like this: `C:\xampp\htdocs\yourprojectname\vendor\bin`.

   4. Restart your Command Prompt (or PowerShell) window, then type `phpunit --version` to see the that it's PHPUnit 6.x.x now.

P.S. (If you want latest PHPUnit do not use ^6.0 in require string, since it will install v6.0.0, write it in composer.lock file that will never update PHPunit to the latest e.g. 6.2.1 version atm). Just use

```
composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit
```

to install the latest stable version for your project.

Answer (score 0):

If you use XAMPP, why don't you update XAMPP version of global PHPUnit to desired.

1.
Read this post, which quickly explains what to do:
[StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43188375/436443)

2.
You can get phar file for version you need here:
[proper PHPUnit phar file](https://phar.phpunit.de/)

3.
Which version of PHPUnit you need depends on your PHP version and you can identify it here:
[which phar file version you need](https://phpunit.de/getting-started/phpunit-7.html)

Just click on links: PHPUnit 9 - PHPUnit 8 - PHPUnit 7 - PHPUnit 6 - PHPUnit 5 - PHPUnit 4 and read description explaining which PHP version it works with.